# When I try starting my Honda it’s hestitant then it starts

Tags: engine, honda, electrical, starting, hesitation

I have a 2004 Honda Accord and when I go too start it, it doesn’t Just start right up like it stutters then starts. I took it too Autozone and had them check battery starter and alternator. They are all good. I replaced the ignition switch and it still does it. What could it be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was there an issue with the ignition switch to cause you to change it? Or was it an assumption on your part it might be the issue? Are there any codes present? Have you checked the fuel pressure at the rail? When was the last time the fuel filter was changed?

Comment: If you hold key to on, then count to ten, then turn to start, does it always start right up?  (check valve at fuel pump stuck open, letting fuel drain from engine back into tank...)